# Can Artifactory and Xray use a common RDS PostgreSQL instance?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

We already have RDS instance used by Artifactory, and want to deploy Xray. We would like to use the same RDS instance if possible. Configuring the same SQL url/username/password details in for the Xray deployment produced this error:

> 2021-04-26T16:58:36.852Z [jfxr ] [ERROR] [                ] [sql_layer:253                 ] [main                ] Failed to Initialize xray DB tables: pq: column "name" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a problem sharing the same DB instance. You should have a dedicated DB schema for each product. The error you got might be related to resources with similar names.

See [Artifactory setup](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/PostgreSQL) and [Xray setup](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Xray).

In the case of Kubernetes, there is a [Helm chart](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/jfrog-platform) to install the whole [JFrog Platform](https://jfrog.com/platform/) using a single PostgreSQL server. You can see how it uses a single [setup script](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/blob/master/stable/jfrog-platform/files/setupPostgres.sh) to prepare each app's DB schema.

Comment: Any way to expand on the "resources with similar names"? We're not using the unified helm chart (it's listed as beta, for one).

Comment: I suspect that there might be overlapping tables with same names between the products that cause this conflict. Anyway - you must have a different DB schema for each product (Artifactory and Xray).